# How to let a multiline string returned by a function appear on multiple lines in a Vue template?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

Quite straightforward but can't get it to work.

My method returns `${a}-${b}` and in my template `<td>{{ myFunction() }}</td>`

So right now it returns A-B in my cell. I'd like to return
A and then B on a new line. I've tried  `${a}\n${b}` or \n\ but it doesn't seem to be working.

Any suggestions ?

Thank you

Comment: console.log(\`${a}\n${b}\`) This puts new line between a b.

Comment: I agree, but it's not the case in the return of my method. In my template, `${a}\n${b}` returns A B on a single line. Not sure if i should change the html or the js on this one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Vue, you are operating on HTML Template.

So you should use `<br/>` instead of `\n`

Instead of using `<td>{{ myFunction() }}</td>`
You may use:

```
<td :html="myFunction()"></td>
```

NOTE: you must make sure that you trust the output of `myFunction` to not contain malicious code (XSS Attack)

Comment: That makes sense. ${a}<br/>${b} returns A<br/>B, am I missing something ?

Comment: try adding a  [v-html directive](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML)

Comment: @GuillaumeBB that's because it's being escaped.

Comment: Well, TIL about v-html. Works like a charm, thanks !

Answer (score 0):

This is due to whitespace collapsing in HTML. You can use the CSS `white-space` property to preserve new lines if set to one of the following values:

- `pre`
- `pre-wrap`
- `pre-line`
- `break-spaces`

Experiment with the above values to see which you prefer (`pre-line` is what I'm using for a similar situation).

There is a table on MDN that lists all values: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space#values

Unless you're absolutely, 100% sure that your `a` and `b` values are properly sanitized and/or will *never* contain user generated content, I would avoid the use of `v-html`. As you're only concerned about preserving newlines, the CSS `white-space` property is exactly what you need.